# Download files from directory and sub-directory - Using Java, JSP

Tags: java, jsp, spring-boot, jstl

I am developing a sample application to download log files from directory and its sub-directory. I am using Spring Boot and jsp technologies for my application.

The ReviewController class mentioned below is responsible for listing all files from specified directory i.e. from EXTERNAL_FILE_PATH and its sub-directory and sending the same list to review.jsp page.

```
@Controller
public class ReviewController {

    private static final String EXTERNAL_FILE_PATH = "C:\\work\\demo-logs\\";


    @RequestMapping("/review")
    public ModelAndView reviewPage() {
        String root=EXTERNAL_FILE_PATH;
        java.io.File file;
        java.io.File dir = new java.io.File(root);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> fileList =displayDirectoryContents(dir,list);
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("review");
        model.addObject("lists", fileList);
        return model;


    }

    public List<String> displayDirectoryContents(File dir,List<String> list) {

        try {
            File[] files = dir.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    System.out.println("directory:" + file.getName());

                    displayDirectoryContents(file,list);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("     file:" + file.getName());
                    list.add(file.getName());
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }

}
```

My review.jsp code is as shown below.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Logs Monitoring App</h1>

    </br>
    </br>

    </br>
    <c:if test="${not empty lists}">

        <ul>
            <c:forEach var="listValue" items="${lists}">

                <li><a href='/download/file/<c:out value="${listValue}"  />'>${listValue}</a>
            </c:forEach>
        </ul>

    </c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above jsp, I am iterating the list and displaying file name as hyperlink.

I have one more controller which is responsible for downloading the files when user clicks a link in jsp. Below is the code for same

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/download")
public class LogFileDownloadController {

    private static final String EXTERNAL_FILE_PATH = "C:\\work\\demo-logs\\";

    @RequestMapping("/file/{fileName:.+}")
    public void downloadPDFResource(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            @PathVariable("fileName") String fileName) throws IOException {

        File file = new File(EXTERNAL_FILE_PATH + fileName);

        if (file.exists()) {


            String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(file.getName());
            if (mimeType == null) {

                mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
            }

            response.setContentType(mimeType);




            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format("inline; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\""));
response.setContentLength((int) file.length());

            InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

            FileCopyUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());

        }
    }

}
```

My concerns are as follows.

1. In my jsp, I am able to show file names present under main directory and its sub-directory. But only able to download files from main directory. i.e.
   "C:\work\demo-logs\" but not able to download files which are
   present under nested directory. for example, files present under
   "C:\work\demo-logs\sub\". Please suggest how can I achieve it?
2. Do i need to use any other technology other than jsp for easy
   implementations. I also need  to show directory name and
   sub-directory name and when user clicks on it, it should expand and
   show the files present under it.once user clicks on file name it should get download.

Comment: Hi All, is there any way we can send file.getAbsolutePath() path parameter to controller method? I tried with below approach @RequestMapping("/download/{fileName:.+}")
 public void downloadLogFiles(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
   @PathVariable("fileName") String fileName) throws IOException {}. But by this, when I click on the link in the jsp file, it is not reaching to my controller. If I use, file.getName() then it is reaching. To download files from nested directories, i am using file.getAbsolutePath().

Answer (score 1):

you can user Files.walk to make it easier. it has depth in argument so that you can specify the depth level for the sub directories.

first create a path object.

Path file_path = Paths.get("/home/User/mypath");

then list the directories with sub directories

```
public Stream<Path> loadFiles() {
    try {
        return Files.walk(file_path, 1)
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("\"Failed to read stored file");
    }
}
```

you can change the depth as Files.walk(file_path, 2)
and if u you want you can filter for files and directories as

Files.walk(file_path, 1).filter(Files::isRegularFile)